# Calculate the conditional probability of a joint p.d.f

Tags: r, montecarlo

I have a joint p.d.f.
And I am now comparing the theoretical value of the conditional probability and the empirical value which I 
ran the Monte Carlo Approach.
I have to do this in replications 10,000, 100,000, and 1,000,000 draws. May I ask how to put replications in the R code?

Also, for the last step, the conditional probability,
I was using Monte Carlo Approach to do it.
Is there any R code which I can use for multivariate Uniform
distribution to calculate the conditional probability?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated! Thanks!!

My code was as below:

```
# f(x.y) = (1/4)*xy, 0<x<2, 0<y<2
# Find P(A) = P(X>1)
f <- function(x){(1/2)*x} # Marginal P(X)
probE <-integrate(f, lower = 1, upper = 2)
cat('\n Pr[ 1 < X ] is \n')
print(probE)

n <- 10000
x<-runif(n, 1,2)
probE.MC <- ((2-1)/n)*sum((1/2)*x)
cat('\n Monte Carlo Pr[1< X ] =',probE.MC,'\n')   

# Find P(B) = P(Y<1)
f <- function(y){(1/2)*y} # Marginal P(Y)
probB <-integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = 1)
cat('\n Pr[ 1< Y ] is \n')
probB


typeof(probB)

n <- 10000
y<-runif(n, 0,1)
probB.MC <- ((1-0)/n)*sum((1/2)*y)
cat('\n Monte Carlo Pr[Y < 1] =',probB.MC,'\n') 

# Pr[A intersect B]
# P[X>1 and Y <1]

f <- function(x,y){return((1/4)*x*y)}
n <- 100000
a11<-1; a12 <-2; a21 <- 0; a22 <-1
x <-runif(n, a11, a12)
y <- runif(n,a21, a22)

probMC <-  ((a12-a11)*(a22-a21)/n)*sum(f(x,y))
probMC
typeof(probMC)

# P[A|B] = p[A intersect B]/ P(B)
  probAB <- probMC/probB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I reformatted the functions and gave them separate names.

```
fX <- function(x) {
    0.5 * x # Marginal P(X)
}
# Find P(B) = P(Y<1)
fY <- function(y) {
    0.5 * y # Marginal P(Y)
}
fXY <- function(x, y) {
    1 / length(x) * sum(0.25 * x * y) # joint X,Y
}
```

The simplest way to do multiple runs is to wrap the MC code in a for loop and save each calculation in an array. Then, at the end, take the mean of the stored values.

So for P[A] you have:

```
n <- 10000
probA.MC <- numeric(n) # create the array
for (i in 1:10000) {
    x<-runif(n, 1,2)
    probA.MC[i] <- ((2-1) / n) * sum(0.5 * x)
}
cat('\n Monte Carlo Pr[1 < X] =',mean(probA.MC),'\n')
```

(I assume probE.MC should have been probA.MC.) The result was `Monte Carlo Pr[1 < X] = 0.7500088`. The code is analogous for P[B] and that result as `Monte Carlo Pr[Y < 1] = 0.2499819`.

For the joint probability we use fXY.

```
n <- 10000
probMC <- numeric(n)
for (i in 1:10000) {
    x <- runif(n, 1, 2)
    y <- runif(n, 0, 1)
    probMC[i] <- ((a12-a11) * (a22-a21)) * fXY(x, y)
}
cat('\n Monte Carlo Pr[X,Y] =',mean(probMC),'\n')
```

This result was `Monte Carlo Pr[X,Y] = 0.1882728`.

The last calculation you did should read as follows (note the probB$value from the integration result):

```
# P[A|B] = p[A intersect B]/ P(B)
probAB <- mean(probMC) / probB$value
print(probAB)
```

This calculation yielded the result `0.7530913`.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much for your help!! But may I ask why we have to use the "mean" of the probMC? Thank you! This is very helpful!

Comment: You've estimated probMC 10,000 times with 10,000 samples each. To estimate the accuracy of the MC estimate we can use the difference from some centrality measure of those 10,000 values (median works as well). Other error measures can be used, of course (RMS for example). (I've edited the code to fix a couple of errors, such as `fXY`.)